# How to provide support for Persistent Volume provisioner within an kubernetes cluster?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Ok so this might be a basic question, but i'm new to kubernetes and tried to install wordpress using helm unto it, using the stable/wordpress chart, but i keep getting an error "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)" is this because of the requirement in here https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/wordpress. "PV provisioner support in the underlying infrastructure" how do i enable this in my infrastructure, i have setup my cluster across three nodes on digitalocean, i've tried searching for tutorials on this, with no luck until now. Please let me know what i'm missing, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PersistentVolume** types are implemented as plugins. Kubernetes currently supports the following plugins:

```
GCEPersistentDisk
AWSElasticBlockStore
AzureFile
AzureDisk
FC (Fibre Channel)
Flexvolume
Flocker
NFS
iSCSI
RBD (Ceph Block Device)
CephFS
Cinder (OpenStack block storage)
Glusterfs
VsphereVolume
Quobyte Volumes
HostPath (Single node testing only – local storage is not supported in any way and WILL NOT WORK in a multi-node cluster)
Portworx Volumes
ScaleIO Volumes
StorageOS
```

You can enable support for PVs or Dynamic PVs using thoese plugins.

[detail reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes)

On Digital Ocean you can use block storage for volumes.

[details](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/add-persistent-storage/)

Comment: ijaz, the link you provided to digitalocean is for their experimental kubernetes service (which is currently invite only). out of the plugins that you have listed which one is the easiest to handle (keep in mind i'm a newbie on kubernetes). And also can you give me a simple tutorial link on it, thanks.

Comment: hi , you can use any plugin that support dynamic provisining since you well need it in your deployment. please see the kubernetes documentation for how to use those plugins.

Comment: okay thanks, well i'm familiar with lxc and they mostly recommend using cephfs for high availability apps using clustering, but i've heard good things about glusterfs too. but gluster is block storage and can scale without points of failure based on this article https://technologyadvice.com/blog/information-technology/ceph-vs-gluster/. So i guess i'll try out glusterfs.

Comment: if you are just playing with kubernetes , then just use local disks

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes can be set-up for [Dynamic Volume Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/). This would allow the Chart to run to completion using the default configuration as the PVs would be provisioned on-demand.